# How can I install mod_ssl on an existing Apache2 installation without recompiling Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mod-ssl

Updated question

**Older question**

Is mod_ssl not for versions of Apache over 1.3.41? I've got version 2.2.17 (currently latest)

http://www.modssl.org/

**Original question**

```
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs
Configuring mod_ssl/2.8.30 for Apache/1.3.39
./configure:Error: Installed Apache doesn't contain Extended API (EAPI)
```

That's strange because my Apache version is 2.2.17

```
/etc/init.d/httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.17 (Unix)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Apache2 contains an own mod_ssl, you can compile it in by specifying `--enable-ssl` on the `configure` command when compiling Apache.

- Documentation on mod_ssl for Apache 2.2.x: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html
- `./configure` options for Apache 2.2.x: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/configure.html

Comment: You're right, but if I don't want to recompile Apache, there doesn't appear to be a configure file in {APACHE_INSTALLATION}/modules/ssl

Comment: I've recompiled apache with --enable-ssl, i still don't see mod_ssl.so under modules

Comment: "under modules" - did you mean folder? If you've added `--enable-ssl`, it will be compiled in statically. If you want a DSO (Dynamic Shared Object), add `--enable-mods-shared='ssl'` to the configure command.

Comment: Is it possible to enable mod_ssl without recompiling apache. (please answer with more than just "Yes"...)

Comment: It's technically possible to enable `mod_ssl` if the Apache server supports DSO. You will need `ssl_module` (`mod_ssl.so`) that was compiled for your server. Put it in the right directory (typically `/usr/local/apache2/modules` for custom builds) and add the line `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so` to your `httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 3):

On a solaris SunOS xxxxxxxxxx5.10 Generic_150400-18 sun4v sparc SUNW,T5240 I built the mod_ssl with the following features

- installed in the apache module  dir
- edited httpd.conf to include LoadModule ssl_module         modules/mod_ssl.so

`bash# apxs   -L/path/to/openssl/dir   -I/path/to/openssl/dir/include  -Wc,-fPIC -i -a -c mod_ssl.c`

Answer (score 1):

For Centos/Fedora distro, install mod_ssl

```
#yum search mod_ssl
#yum install mod_ssl
```

Then restart apache and check for ssl module.

```
#httpd -M | grep -i ssl
 ssl_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```